# Autorenewable subscription sandbox test environment iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033673/ios-sandbox-environment-auto-renewal-subscription) answer and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581190/autorenewable-subscriptions-wont-be-autorenewed) but they are quite old so maybe there are some new update.
My issue is about disabling autorenewing on test users, because if I try to do that using the recommended approach of the Apple ID, the stores complains about the user (of course it's test user) and I can't reach the screen where you can disable them.
Is there a way or do I need to wait after the 6 renew?